# jQuery Sortable - How do you prevent the placeholder from appearing when the list is "full"?

Tags: jquery-ui

I am able to prevent a sortable list from taking more than the desired number of elements (in this example 1).

```
receive: function(event, ui) {
    if ($(this).children().length > 1) {
        $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
    }
}
```

But when you drag an item over an already full list, the placeholder appears as if you can drop another item into the list. (It can appear both above and below the current list item).

How can I prevent the placeholder from appearing once the list is full?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add the following:

```
over: function(event, ui) {
    if ($(this).children().length > 1) {
        $(ui.placeholder).css('display', 'none');
    } else {
        $(ui.placeholder).css('display', '');
    }
}

beforeStop: function(event, ui) {
    cancelRequired = ($(this).children().length > 1);
},

stop: function() {
    if (cancelRequired) {
        $(this).sortable('cancel');
    }
}
```